# Converting ampersand (&) and blank space to a dash (-) in URLs using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

With the code below, I have converted the following names into URL such as

- `Love & Relationships` to `http://domain.org/love-relationships`
- `Career & Guidance` to `http://domain.org/career-guidance`

  ```
  filter('ampToDash', function(){
      return function(text){
          return text ? String(text).replace(/ & /g,'-'): '';
      };
  }).filter('dashToAmp', function(){
      return function(text){
          return text ? String(text).replace(/-/g,' & '): '';
      };
  })
  ```

However, I have a new set of names and I can't figure out how to do both at the same time.

- `Being Human` to `http://domain.org/being-human`
- `Competitive Exams` to `http://domain.org/competitive-exams`

  ```
  filter('ampToDash', function(){
      return function(text){
          return text ? String(text).replace(/ /g,'-'): '';
      };
  }).filter('dashToAmp', function(){
      return function(text){
         return text ? String(text).replace(/-/g,' '): '';
      };
  })
  ```

How do I combine both the regex codes so it can work hand in hand?

Comment: Maybe `.replace(/ & | /g, "-")`?

Answer (score 4):

You may also want to extend your replacement criteria to cover all "non-word" characters, instead of just accounting for the ones you're currently aware of (& and space). This would be more future-proof, and perhaps easier to reason with:

```
String(text).replace(/\W+/g, '-')
```

(`\W+` means any sequence of non-word characters.)

Example:

```
'Jack & Jill went up the @$%#! hill'.replace(/\W+/g, '-')
```

Yields:

```
Jack-Jill-went-up-the-hill
```

And because there's loss of information (i.e. you don't know what exactly leads to a '-' by looking at the transformed string), a way you can find the original string is to simply store it and look up by the transformed string. To elaborate: You're probably going to be looking up some document from this new string (a "slug", as others pointed out). Store the slug along with the document and just look up the document (and its original title) from your database.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you simply want to change any instances of an ampersand with leading or trailing white-space or just white-space to a single hyphen. If so, you could just use the following expression :

```
// Replace any strings that have leading and trailing spaces or just a series of spaces
String(text).replace(/(\s+&\s+|\s+)/g,'-'): '';
```

**Example**

[image]

```js
var input = ['Love & Relationships', 'Career & Guidance', 'Being Human', 'Competitive Exams'];
for (var i in input) {
  var phrase = input[i];
  console.log(phrase + ' -> ' + phrase.replace(/(\s+&\s+|\s+)/g, '-'));
}
```

Comment: I assume this would be for `ampToDash`. How should I go about changing it for `dashToAmp `? Thank You.

Comment: Do you mean reversing the process? There really isn't going to be any way for it to know if it should just be converting the hyphen to an ` & ` or just a space ` `. You really aren't going to be able to use a single universal function to handle the backwards / forwards conversion of both examples as it won't know when the ampersand needs to be included again.

Comment: Okay. I was hoping there could be a way out! Thank you once again

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a lib that converts a string into a slug.
You can do this manually, but you'll probably have hard time covering other edge cases.

I would suggest you to use something like :
https://github.com/dodo/node-slug

Or check out this gist if you really want to stay with the regex way : https://gist.github.com/mathewbyrne/1280286

Comment: Thank You. I actually have gone through it but couldn't get a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have two separate problems:

1. how to 'slugify' a string
2. how to undo / reverse the slugify.

To answer 1: A generic slugify method would be something like: `text.replace(/\W+/g, '-')`

To answer 2: you can't.  You have a function (`ampToDash`) that can produce the same output given different inputs.  i.e. there is NO equivalent of `dashToAmp` any more.

Comment: So it's not possible to do this? I was hope it could be done. Thank you for your clarifications.

Comment: No, not possible.  How would you know whether `career-guidance` should map back to `career-guidance`, `Career Guidance`, `Career & Guidance`, `CAREER GUIDANCE` etc?

The way this is normally handled in content-management / blogging-platforms is to store the generated slug in the database, then rip the URL to pieces and lookup article content using the slug as a lookup-key to the database.  You do NOT try and reverse-engineer the article title from the slug.

Comment: Okay. Thank You. I'll talk to the backend guy and see for a solution.